# Construct array in a specific address in C

Tags: c

I want to create an integer array `array[3]` in a specific address `addr`, and initialize the array with `{ 1, 3, 6 }`. How can I do that?

```
int addr = 0x40000;
((int *)addr)[3] = { 1, 3, 6 }; //Error
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't *initialise* an array at that location, and you can't even declare that there is one.

However, you can use a pointer to manipulate values already existing at that location.

In fact, you're pretty close:

```
int* addr = (int*)0x40000;
addr[0] = 1;
addr[1] = 3;
addr[2] = 6;
```

Technically, this may have *undefined behaviour* depending on where this `0x40000` comes from: performing pointer arithmetic (including via array subscripting like this) requires that you are navigating an object or array of objects, which must have been created by your program: if your integers were instead created by some other process (possible, despite virtual memory, if for example you're memory mapping some hardware registers) then this is not strictly the case. However, it will work on basically all hardware and is a common technique.

But if nothing currently exists at `0x40000` and you're trying to specify where a brand new C array will be allocated then, no, you cannot do that.

Comment: This technique can be useful on embedded systems where you can know exactly what is at a given address. (Memory mapped I/O, flash pages, etc.) On the average desktop system, code like this is almost certainly a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Sometimes you'll want to declare the pointer as volatile, as in `volatile int *addr = (volatile int*)0x40000;`. This is useful if the values can change outside of the application context or if setting a value triggers a hardware operation of some sort.